# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered the error while following the rails tutorial. After some research, changing `@post = Post.new(params[:post])` to `@post = Post.new(post_params)` solved my problem, though I still don't quite understand the reason. What made the difference? And why can I use `params[:id]` in `show`?

My posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Comment: check this tutorial. You got the answer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: check [rails 4: Strong parameters](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)..

Comment: check http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-strong_parameters

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, the strong parameters system applies when you try to create or to edit a record. Therefore, a simple SELECT/find in your show action works fine even with unpermitted parameters.
However, you have to explicitly permit parameters in your controller for every INSERT or UPDATE actions. This is what you have done with the `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)`. You have said that the title and the text parameters are permitted if the :post one exists.